# Cypher query help: Order query results by content of property array

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a bunch of venues in my Neo4J DB. Each venue object has the property 'catIds' that is an array and contains the Ids for the type of venue it is. I want to query the database so that I get all Venues but they are ordered where their catIds match or contain some off a list of Ids that I give the query. I hope that makes sense :)

Please, could someone point me in the direction of how to write this query?

Comment: Hello! What you have tried so far? Can you please post a sample of your data set?

Comment: Im new to Neo4J/Cypher, I've no idea where to start with the query lol. By dataset do you mean the Cypher Statement/JS code that creates the Venue nodes?

Comment: _"By dataset do you mean the Cypher Statement/JS code that creates the Venue nodes?"_ Yes. _'I've no idea where to start with the query"_ You probably will be downvoted asking for help with problem that you have not tried nothing yet to solve. Take a look at [Cypher docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/) and in the help center section [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Bruno, Thank you very much!! Here is cypher for node creation:  `UNWIND {venues} AS i MERGE (v:Venue { name: i.name, formattedAddress: i.formattedAddress, latitude: i.latitude, longitude: i.longitude, catNames: i.catNames, catIds:i.catIds }) RETURN v`.

Comment: @NathanHorrigan That info belongs in the question, not in a comment. Also, that is just the creation Cypher (which may be problematical, all on its own), not a query for your wanted results. If you want to get help on creating the query, you will have to at least clarify (in the question, not in a comment) what exactly you want; providing some examples would be good, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working in a graph database you could think about modeling your data in the graph, not in a property where it's hard to get at it.  For example, in this case you might create a bunch of (v:venue) nodes and a bunch of (t:type) nodes, then link them by an [:is] relation.  Each venue is linked to one or more type nodes.  Each type node has an 'id' property: {id:'t1'}, {id:'t2'}, etc.

Then you could do a query like this:

```
match (v:venue)-[r:is]->(:type) return v, count(r) as n order by n desc;
```

This finds all your venues, along with ALL their type relations and returns them ordered by how many type-relations they have.

If you only want to get nodes of particular venue types on your list:

```
match (v:venue)-[r:is]-(t:type) where t.id in ['t1','t2'] return v, count(r) as n order by n desc;
```

And if you want ALL venues but rank ordered according to how well they fit your list, as I think you were looking for:

```
match (v:venue) optional match (v)-[r:is]->(t:type) where t.id in ['t1','t2'] return v, count(r) as n order by n desc;
```

The match will get all your venues; the optional match will find relations on your list if the node has any.  If a node has no links on your list, the optional match will fail and return null for count(r) and should sort to the bottom.

Comment: Amazing Answer, Thank You!!